Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3
# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--`dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '12.2.5.6-1'

